# Replacing values in one dictionary with the keys in another dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have two dictionaries:

```
dict_1 = {0:[300,650], 1:[420,800], 2:[700,400]}
dict_2 =  {0.0: [[300,650], [895, 111]], 1.0: [[700, 400], [420, 800]], 2.0: [[100, 800], [200, 400]]
```

If a value in `dict_1` is equal to one of the values in the lists in `dict_2` then the value in `dict_2` must be replaced with the KEY corresponding to the value in `dict_1`.

From the above dictionaries the output I want is:

`dict_2 = {0.0: [0, [895, 111]], 1.0: [2, 1], 2.0: [[100, 800], [200, 400]]`

This is how far I've gotten:

```
x = 0
for i in dict_2:
    for node in dict_1:
        if dict_2[x][0] == dict_1[x]:
            dict_2[x][0] = dict_1[???]
        if dict_2[x][1] == dict_1[x]:
            dict_2[x][1] = dict_1[???]
    x+=1
```

All I'm really struggling with is how to call the key of `dict_1` and not a value associated with the key of `dict_1` - and obviously my code could be more efficient.

Thanks

Comment: Don't you already have a key of `dict_1` in the variable `node`?

Comment: @Kendas ahah i was blind. that is so true. The dict_1[???], should just be "node"... Since iterating over a dictionnarie is the same as iterating over its keys...

Comment: Moreover, the `dict_1[x]` is the operation of getting the value associated with the _key_ `x` in the dict `dict_1`. Also, you can iterate over both by doing `for key, value in dict_1.items():`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that the values in `dict_1` are unique you reverse it by converting lists to tuples. Then you can use dict comprehension with nested list comprehension to create the final result:

```
dict_1 = {0:[300,650], 1:[420,800], 2:[700,400]}
dict_2 =  {0.0: [[300,650], [895, 111]], 1.0: [[700, 400], [420, 800]], 2.0: [[100, 800], [200, 400]]}

inverse = {tuple(v): k for k, v in dict_1.items()}
res = {k: [inverse.get(tuple(l), l) for l in v] for k, v in dict_2.items()}
print(res)
```

Output:

```
{0.0: [0, [895, 111]], 1.0: [2, 1], 2.0: [[100, 800], [200, 400]]}
```

Comment: Was about to post the same ^^

Answer (score 0):

You can create a reversed dict_1 to have the keys instead of the values.

```
dict_1_rev = {v:k for k,v in a.items()}
```

so :

```
x = 0
for i in dict_2:
    for node in dict_1:
        if dict_2[x][0] == dict_1[x]:
            dict_2[x][0] = dict_1_rev[dict_1[x]]
        if dict_2[x][1] == dict_1[x]:
            dict_2[x][1] = dict_1_rev[dict_1[x]]
    x+=1
```

Note that this cannot work if you have duplicate values in dict one. Keys must be unique for your problem.

Up to you to make it more efficient, though. That is another question.

Answer (score 0):

This should work :

```
dict_1 = {0:[300,650], 1:[420,800], 2:[700,400]}
dict_2 =  {0.0: [[300,650], [895, 111]], 1.0: [[700, 400], [420, 800]], 2.0: [[100, 800], [200, 400]]}

for key_2 in dict_2:
    for key_1 in dict_1:
        for i in range(0, len(dict_2[key_2])): # In case you change the dimension of dict_2
            if dict_2[key_2][i] == dict_1[key_1]:
                dict_2[key_2][i] = key_1
```